# Slider not beeing updated after apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object model which contains the view information. When I do some changes on this object and then I use the apply, every component but the slider are updated. I can see the slider updated only after a resize on the window. Any idea?

```
$rootScope.$on('newPrintSelected', function (event, selectedPrinter) {
        StorageModule.storage.find(collectionName, {_id : selectedPrinter.printer_hardware._id}, function(error, data){
            if (error) { //Not Found
                console.error("Ops. There is something wrong with this action...");
            }else {
                    if(data[0].printOptions == null){
                        $scope.options = angular.copy($scope.default);
                        $scope.options.layerThickness = 30 - ($scope.options.layerThickness * 100);
                        $scope.persistedOptions = angular.copy($scope.default);
                        $scope.persistedOptions.layerThickness = 30 - ($scope.persistedOptions.layerThickness * 100);
                    }else{
                        data[0].printOptions.layerThickness = 30 - (data[0].printOptions.layerThickness * 100);
                        $scope.options = angular.copy(data[0].printOptions);
                        $scope.persistedOptions = angular.copy(data[0].printOptions);
                    }
                }
                $scope.selectedPrinterHardware = angular.copy(data[0]);
                console.warn($scope.options);
                $scope.$apply();
            });
    });
```

Slider:

```
<div class="slider">
   <rzslider rz-slider-model="options.infill" rz-slider-options="slider.infill">

    </rzslider>
</div>
```

$scope.options is the object used as model. console.warn($scope.options); shows that the object is correct.

**Fix:**

```
setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender'); }, 25);
```

For every time that the Slider is showen.

This was on the documentation. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: Where is the slider?

Comment: @ajmajmajma Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about broadcasting a refresh event:

```
$scope.refreshSlider = function () {
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender');
  });
};
```

[Reference 1](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider)  [Reference 2](http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/)

Comment: I made this horrible mistake of not check the documentation. I'm sorry for this question. @Manu, your answer helped me but i had to change it a little bit to work. Check the last update, please.